# Is there any incidence of Portend or fortell (bhavishyavani) in scriptures except Krishna birth?

Tags: krishna

Is there any incidence of Aakashvaani in scriptures except Krishna birth? Bhavishyavani of something in scriptures?

Comment: There was Akash Vani during birth of Sishupal..

Comment: There is an incident in Sri Ramacharitamanas. The incident took place when Kagabhushundi (as Brahman) had a heated discussion with sage Lomasha and the latter cursed the former to become a crow. Then there was askashvaani that declared Kagabhushundi to be a true devotee of Sri Rama in thought(mana), speech(vachan) and actions(karma).

Comment: I don't know about akashvaani but there is a bhavishyavani in Shrimad bhagwat Mahapurana about Kalki avatar which is yet to be fulfilled. http://www.stephen-knapp.com/kalki_the_next_avatar_of_God.htm

Comment: I vaguely remember watching an episode of Narsimha avatar in one of TV Series, where it was shown that when Narsimha is about to kill Hiranyakasypu, there was an Aakashvani. But no scriptural basis to support this incidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there are lots of incidents. One example occurs in Mahabharata Vana Parva
in the story of Bhageeratha. The sloka is athāntarikṣācchuśrāva vācaṃ gambhīraniḥsvanām । meaning a loud voice spoke from Aakash or Antariksha. You can refer that at https://archive.org/details/mahabharata02ramauoft page 346 (of the document, not the book) sloka 21.